# Prevent Rails from caching results of ActiveRecord query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

I have a rake task that needs to iterate through a large number of records (called Merchants) which each have a large number of associated items.  My problem is that due to Rails automatically caching the results of my DB queries, I end up putting my workers into swap space before very long.

In short, I'm wondering how to run a command like:

`Merchant.all.each { |m| items = m.items }`

without caching the value of 'items' each time through.

I've tried:

```
Merchant.all.each do |m|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.uncached do
   items = m.items
 end
end
```

and I've also tried adding this to my Merchant model:

```
def items_uncached
  self.class.uncached { items }
end
```

and then calling items_uncached instead, but I still end up racking up the memory usage with each new set of items I access.

I'm running Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.9.2 and using Mysql for storage.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

*** edit:

HEre's the actual bit of code I'm working on:

```
File.open(output, "w") do |f|
  Merchant.all.each do |m|
    items = m.items
    invalid_image_count = 0
    items.each do |i|
      invalid_image_count += 1 unless i.image_valid?
    end
    invalid_categories = items.select { |i| !i.categories_valid? }.count
    f.puts "#{m.name} (#{m.id}): #{invalid_image_count} invalid images, " +
            "#{invalid_categories} invalid categories"
  end
end
```

Trying to do some error checking and then logging the results.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't very clear here; maybe you're looking for something like `ActiveRecord::Base#find_each`?

Comment: Okay, yeah I just looked at find_each and that could be helpful actually.  I'll try it.

Comment: To articulate a little better, when I run this code in console: Merchant.all.each { |m| items = m.items ; print "#{m.id} " }, there's a bump in my memory usage on each iteration.  My guess was that this was due to the fact that m.items yields between 1 and 10,000+ ActiveRecords.

Comment: That's expected: Ruby's garbage collector is very infrequently triggered, so it's unlikely to release memory when it exits the block. Instead it will re-use it when it gets the next results. If the next set of results is larger, more memory will be allocated. This doesn't account for a potential memory leak in AR (or Rails, or a gem/plugin, or your code, etc). I don't know much about 2.3 (started with 3), but I don't think it does query caching without explicitly turning it on (i.e. using memcache).

Comment: what is items, anyways?  what does that code actually do?  Is it in it's own block or something and you've just taken this chunk out?

Comment: @coreyward -- i had thought that the results of sql queries were cached by default in rails. if that's not the case then there should definitely be some setting i should be able to switch (and in that case sorry for not having looked through the app thoroughly enough to begin with).

Comment: @pjammer - added my code to the original post. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @pjammer - also, items are ActiveRecords. each merchant has 0:N associated items. m.items just returns all of the items for a merchant.

Comment: Stumbled across this by accident. For anybody else who equally arrives 2 years late and wants to know how to prevent the caching of the query, I believe the issue is actually that the block for `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.uncached do ... end ` should be around the `.all` query. This prevents a cache put for the `select * from table` query being performed, which is just a waste. The individual objects are still accessible in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your association is a simple `has_many` one you can try this:

```
Merchant.all.each do |m| 
  items = Item.find_all_by_merchant_id(m.id) 
  ...
end
```

Or even:

```
Merchant.find(:all, :select => "id, name").each do |m| 
  items = Item.find_all_by_merchant_id(m.id) 
  ... 
end
```

Comment: i'm not sure if this avoids caching though. it is a simple has_many relationship, but i think that in this case, m.items should have the same effect/return value as Item.find_all_by_merchant_id(m.id). does that sound right?

Comment: I believe `m.items` will not be released until you release `Merchant.all` array (i. e. until you finish `each` loop), while in my case `items` will be released and garbage collected after you reassign it on the next `each` iteration.

Answer (score 4):

The query cache is not the main problem here. Rails "caches" your objects anyway.

The query cache is simply a "hash lookup" that prevents Rails from hitting the DB unnecessarily, it does not control how ruby (or Rails) stores objects internally returned by associations.

For example try this (even if uncached):

```
m = Merhant.first # <- m is loaded from DB
m.items           # <- items are loaded from DB and STORED(!) in m
m.items           # <- items are returned from the association stored in m
m.items.reload    # <- hits the DB (or the query cache)
m.instance_variable_get("@items") # <- returns the actual stored items
```

So now when you do `m.items` in your `each` loop you simply populate all the `Merhcant` instances with all their items, and the garbage collector is unable to free anything since all the objects are referenced from the `all` array while you are inside the loop.

So the solution is to do like Victor proposes, which prevents the "association storage" from triggering.